# WordPress query loop div display

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop

Hello I want to display posts like this.

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="row">
    Post No 1.
    Post No 2.
  </div>
  <div class=row 2>
    Post No 3.
    Post No 4.
    Post No 5.
  <div>
</div>
```

Here is code what i am trying.

```
 <?php 
                    global $paged, $wp_query, $wp;
                    $arags = array(
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'posts_per_page' => 5,
                    );
                    $count = 1;
                    $itemClass = '';
                    $wp_query = new WP_Query($arags);
                    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
                    ?>
                    <?php 
                    if($count == 1) :
                        echo '<div class="item">';
                        echo '<div class="row">';
                    endif;

                    if($count == 1 || $count == 2) :
                        get_template_part( 'templates/mag/mag-loop-big' );
                    endif;


                    if($count == 1) :
                        echo '</div>';
                        echo '</div>';
                    endif;
                    ?>
                    <?php $count++; ?>                      
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

This Code display first post in Item and Div class.
But second div shown out side of row and item div.
Here is current result.

```
<div class="item">
<div class="row">
    Post No 1.
 </div>
</div>
 Post No 2.
 Post No 3.
Post No 4.
```

Any solution for this??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: show the result of your codes

Comment: Because you have closed div after first post `if($count == 1) :
                        echo '</div>';
                        echo '</div>';
                    endif;`

Comment: Result added Question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your conditions are not the right one for that result try this

```
if($count == 1) :
echo '<div class="item">';
echo '<div class="row">';
if($count == 1) :
get_template_part( 'templates/mag/mag-loop-big' );
endif;
if($count == 2) :
echo '</div>';
endif;
 if($count == 3) :
 echo '<div class="row2">';
 if($count == 5) :
 echo '</div>';
 echo '</div>';
 endif;
?>
```